# Multiple reverse foreign key traversal

Tags: django, django-models

I have several tables that go one-to-many in one direction:

```
class ShiftGroup(models.Model):
    def getJobType(self):
        ???

class Shift(models.Model):
    shift_group = models.ForeignKey(ShiftGroup, related_name="shifts")

class Run(models.Model): 
    shift = models.ForeignKey(Shift, related_name="runs")

class Job(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, related_name="jobs", blank=True, null=True)
    job_type = models.ForeignKey(JobType, related_name="jobs")
```

In my view, I am pulling a queryset of ShiftGroups to display in a table, but I need to also display the job_type.  I know I can pull information from shift using

```
ShiftGroup.shifts.all()
```

but is there any way to call

```
ShiftGroup.shifts.runs.jobs.job_types
```

in the view or template without needing to do nested for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense as posed. As you know, each ShiftGroup has multiple shifts, each Shift has multiple runs, as so on. So there is no such thing as "the job_type" for a ShiftGroup: there are many.

If you're asking for a list of all job_types in jobs in runs in shifts in the current ShiftGroup, then you should start with JobType, and use the double-underscore syntax:

```
JobType.objects.filter(job__run__shift__shift_group=self)
```

but again, this is a *list* of jobtypes, not a single one. If it is the case that all these relationships can only end in a case where there is one single jobtype, then you have something wrong with your data modelling: perhaps you should have a direct ForeignKey from ShiftGroup to JobType.

Comment: okay, thats what I figured.  Thanks Daniel, I'll look into making an association table between shift_groups and job_types

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you might do something like this:

```
{% for shift in shiftgroups.shift_set.all %}
  {% for run in shift.run_set.all %}
    {% for job in run.job_set.all %}
      {{ job.job_type }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This may be somewhat expensive though if you have lots of objects.